# Java libGDX: How to change Music speed?

Tags: libgdx

I am developing a game using libGDX and want to control the speed multiplier of Music, such as accelerating playback by 5 times and 10 times, similar to the function of holding down the space in the GBA emulator.

I've finished speeding up the animation. It is to multiply delta by the speed multiplier under the render method, but Music cannot achieve it.

Comment: ```Music``` doesn't have a ```setPitch``` but ```Sound``` does if your sound is short enough to switch over.

Comment: Yes, I found it, I'm going to try to see if `Sound` can fulfill my needs